# The system failed to create the file ... Permission Denied - cPanel

Tags: cpanel, privileges, whmcs

I have a cPanel account which is attached to my site on WHMCS. I tried editing the site by editing the files inside the 'templates' folder in the cPanel, but when I click on SAVE CHANGES, I get the following error -

*The system failed to create the file “/home/levellight/public_html/templates/BoxChat/about-us.tpl.lock” (as EUID: 512, EGID: 511 511) because of the following error: Permission denied*

I have tried several things to make this work, but none worked. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you provide more explanations on what you've tried, what failed, etc. Please take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way:

1. create a new folder next to parent folder.
2. copy everything from parent folder to the new folder.
3. edit parent folder name and rename the new folder to parent folder's name.
4. (* then delete parent folder if every things working fine)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the file permission:

1. Login in your Cpanel
2. Click the right button on select folder
3. Click [Change Permissions], changing the Permissions 0777.

Note, be careful, not all folders and files allow this. Some knowledge about Permissions is needed.